# Set Min and Max text size in EditTextPreference

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-preferences

How to set max and min text size using EditTextPreference? I.e. when max value =22, but user  for example set 25, he receives Toast from the comfort of settings "Max value is 22" and text size  does not change to 25

Comment: This needs more information and code so we have an idea of what you are going incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

Use this class for filter :

```
package com.test;

import android.text.InputFilter;
import android.text.Spanned;

public class InputFilterMinMax implements InputFilter {

    private int min, max;

    public InputFilterMinMax(int min, int max) {
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;
    }

    public InputFilterMinMax(String min, String max) {
        this.min = Integer.parseInt(min);
        this.max = Integer.parseInt(max);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {   
        try {
            int input = Integer.parseInt(dest.toString() + source.toString());
            if (isInRange(min, max, input))
                return null;
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) { }     
        return "";
    }

    private boolean isInRange(int a, int b, int c) {
        return b > a ? c >= a && c <= b : c >= b && c <= a;
    }
}
```

Use :

```
EditText editText1 = ((EditTextPreference) findPreference(preference_1_key))
                         .getEditText();
editText1.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{ new InputFilterMinMax(1, 30) });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by two ways,

1) Set both Maximum and Minimum Size of font in sharedpreference and then access it from there on the screen from where user will set font size.

2) If your size is fixed and it will not change continuously then declare it in the activity itself as final, and then compare it when user will select font size.

For better understanding provide your code so will do changes and show you properly.